# Using wildcard routes with fastify

Tags: node.js, routes, fastify

I am working on an SSR server. I have a single catch-all dynamic route - `loader` for all GET requests, and I am using `fastify-static` to handle everything else.

```
const main = async () => {
  process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  });

  const server = fastify({ logger: true });
  server.register(shutdown);

  server.register(compress);
  server.get('/*', fp(loader));
  server.register(require('fastify-static'), {
    root: path.join(__dirname, '../build/static'),
    prefix: '/static'
  });

  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
  const address = await server.listen(PORT);
  server.log.info(`Server running at: ${address}`);

  server.gracefulShutdown((signal, next) => {
    next();
  });
  module.exports = server;
};
```

In order for `fastify-static` to not conflict with dynamic routes, I added a prefix. This works fine, for the most part. However, it does leave me with a couple of problems still:

- `{"method":"GET","url":"/manifest.json","hostname":"localhost:3000","remoteAddress":"127.0.0.1","remotePort":50382},"msg":"incoming request"}` returns 404
- my static route would not help with `<link href="/icons/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">`

What is the easiest way of handling routes: `/manifest.json` and `/icon/favicon.ico`?

Comment: There is a conflict between the `fastify-static` and your `/*` route. Which one should serve the HTTP request?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I need `fastify-static` to serve the static file named `manifest.json` from `../build/manifest.json` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended-up with the below:

Multiple handlers for static assets with disabled decorators:

```
  server.register(require('fastify-static'), {
    root: path.join(__dirname, '../build/static'),
    prefix: '/static',
    decorateReply: false
  });
  server.register(require('fastify-static'), {
    root: path.join(__dirname, '../build/icons'),
    prefix: '/icons',
    decorateReply: false
  });
```

A special handler for the `/manifest.json` route inside my loader:

```
export default (req, res) => {
   if (req.url === '/manifest.json') {
     fs.readFile(
       path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/manifest.json'),
       'utf8',
       (err, manifest) => {
         // If there's an error... serve up something nasty
         if (err) {
           console.error('Read error', err);

           return res.status(404).end();
         }

         res.send(manifest);
       }
     );
     return;
   }
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are deprecated. Please use:

```
import Fastify from 'fastify';
const fastify = Fastify({ logger: true });
import fastifyStatic from '@fastify/static';

fastify.register(fastifyStatic, {
    root: path.join(__dirname),
    prefix: '/w/public/',
});
```

Of course install latest version npm i `@fastify/static@5.0.0`